# Permission Denied for about everything on Powershell

Tags: powershell, unauthorizedaccessexcepti

Trying to create a directory in c:\powershell responds with

- CategoryInfo          : PermissionDenied: (C:\powershell:String) [New-Item], UnauthorizedAccessException

  - FullyQualifiedErrorId : CreateDirectoryUnauthorizedAccessError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewItemCommand

So far I have tried:

1. Set-ExecutionPolicy to "Unrestricted"
2. Run as Administrator
3. Used -force
4. Tried to give myself access to v1.0 but it doesn't let me

I am clueless and I hope someone could help me.

Comment: You could start by actually *showing* us the code you're trying to run. The error message looks stranger than usual; "c:\powershell:String" seems to be the thing you're being denied on and that is not a valid folder name on Windows. Your code probably contains problems.

Comment: @veefu that's just the format of error messages.  It's `(<ErrorRecord target object as string>:<actual type of ErrorRecord target object>)`. @vlaeden you probably just don't have rights to create a file there.  A lot of environments deny rights to the root of C even for administrators.

Comment: Yeah, I'd try the same code targeting like your documents and you can verify its folder permissions. Doing stuff directly off C:\ causes permission issues pretty frequently.

Comment: This is not a PowerShell question but rather a "how do NTFS file system permissions work" question (i.e., more appropriate for superuser or serverfault).

Comment: @PatrickMeinecke was right, I just didn't have the rights so I chose another way to do it, now it works. to Sambardo: Yeah, I've just gone through that, you're right. Bill_Stewart: I agree, it turned out just to be that, powershell did nothing wrong. Thank you all for your help, really glad you were here for me.